# Dynamically change data layer event based on URL path

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, marketo, google-datalayer

I wish to have my datalayer push my event data dynamically. At the moment I need to change the statement manual however if I am to scale this up to 100 pages it can get annoying.

Is there a simple way to have the statement detect my URL path and populate the event with the path name ?

```
 MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form) {
        form.onSuccess(function (values, followUpUrl) {

            pathname = window.location.pathname;

            if (pathname == "/contact.html") {
                dataLayer.push({event: 'Contact', eventLabel: form.getId()});
            } else return null;

        });
    });
```

Comment: Your post does not elaborate on your title. You probably want to either change the title, or update the post. Probably the latter, because if you just wanted to detect whether the URL has a `#` using JavaScript, there are hundreds if not thousands of answers for that on the internet already.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, ive updated both.